# PHP how to stop writing and truncate

Tags: php, concurrency, fopen, atomic, fwrite

I'm trying to implement a kind of atomic get and set in php. Here is what I got so far.

```
function atomic_get_and_set($filename, $oldData, $newData)
{
  $size = filesize($filename) + 100000;
  $fp = fopen($filename, "c+");
  $failure = "0";
  if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
    $current_content = fread($fp, $size);
    if($current_content == $oldData) {
      rewind($fp);
      fwrite($fp, $newData);
    } else {
      $failure = "1".$current_content;
    }
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
  }
  fclose($fp);
  return $failure;
}
```

I'm trying to return the content of the file preceded with "1" if what we read is not the expected old dated, "0" and write to the file otherwise.

I had to open the file using C+ or a+ to make sure I don't delete the file content when I open it.
However, the following scenario fails:

```
 file_put_contents("test.txt", "hello world");
 atomic_get_and_set("test.txt", "hello world", "hallo");
```

Indeed, the result of the file is "hallo world" instead of just "hallo", because I did not find how to tell him to finish to write the file after the `fwrite`. Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: [Any reason you're not just using `file_get_contents`](https://3v4l.org/WfHYs)? Can you elaborate on exactly what should happen depending on what the file contains, and at what position?

Comment: I just want to read the file, do some test on the content, and if the test is positive, I write the file. I don't want someone else to write on the file between reading the file and writing the file. That's what I'm trying to achieve.